# How to do a memory dump in Bochs?

Tags: memory, dump, bochs

How do you do a memory dump in [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net)?

(Either physical or virtual -- but *both* would be even better!)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has already been a while, but I had the same problem and I could solve.

### GUI Debug

Bochs accompanies a visual debugger that can be activated with the following flags in

```
./configure \
--enable-x86-debugger \
--enable-debugger \
--enable-debugger-gui
```

when you will build it, and add this option in your Bochs configuration file:

```
display_library: x, options = "gui_debug"
```

With the gui debugger open, you can at any time press the "break" button and in the View menu, you have the "Physical MemDump" and "Linear MemDump" options, just enter the start address and bochs will dump 4kB for you.

### Without GUI Debug

If you prefer, you can also use the text mode, the breakpoint can be set with the command "lbreak addr" (for linear) or "pbreak addr" (physical), to list the configured breakpoints just type "info break" and to delete them "d number". Single step (s) and to continue execution (continue).

With the execution paused, you can dump with the "x" (linear) and "xp" (physical) followed by some optional parameters such as the output format, number of bytes, and the address, for example.

Example:

```
x /30bx 0xC0000000
```

will make 30 bytes dump in hexadecimal format from the linear address 0xC0000000.

#### Writing in the file

In some cases, the dump can be large enough to be read on the screen. In these cases you can do it to a file using the command "writemem".

Its syntax is:

```
writemem "filename" linearAddress lenght_in_bytes
```

so if you need to dump the first 1024 bytes of the linear address 0xdeadbeef to the "dump" file, something like:

```
writemem "dump" 0xdeadbeef 1024
```

should work.

Please refer to http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [Save and restore simulation](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/using-save-restore.html):

> The state of cpu(s), **memory** and all devices can be saved now. When running Bochs with there will be a button in the header bar called "Suspend".

(emphasis added)

Comment: Er... yes, the contents of the memory is there, but how do I look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `memsave` and `pmemsave` commands in the Bochs console.

> ‘`memsave addr size file`’
>
> save to disk virtual memory dump starting at addr of size size.
>
> ‘`pmemsave addr size file`’
>
> save to disk physical memory dump starting at addr of size size.

Comment: Are you sure Bochs supports this?

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is [`writemem`](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html)

```
    writemem                     dump a number of bytes of virtual memory starting from
                                 the specified linear address into a file
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Update me if you do get this to work somehow